# Ember Models and SQL - Joining tables on server or via Ember relationships?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ember.js, models

With Ember, you can find a number of tutorials on building blogs and to do lists, but there doesn't seem to be much on anything that requires more complex models. I'm looking for a little more guidance as to whether or not there are best practices for dealing with complex normalized data in Ember.

For instance, I'm working on a wine cellar app, and I'm using 8 different tables to model bottles of wine (though the details aren't really important):

```
wines
categories
bottle_varietals
wine_varietals
producers
appellations
regions
countries
```

In order to display the wine bottles, I will need to join all of this data. I see two ways of doing that:

1. Do a join on the server side, and send a package of wine bottles to the client where you'd only have a `wine_bottle` model.
2. Create 8 Ember models that correspond to each table, and create Ember relationships with `hasMany`, `belongsTo`, etc.

Both ways seem feasible and like they would have their advantages and disadvantages. Given that Ember is an 'opinionated' framework, is there an 'Ember Way' on this one, or does this just come down to developer tastes?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: I think that it is left to the user tastes. Details below:

If you want to represent the resources like producers/bottle_varietals, then you should go with your second approach. However if you are only interested in handling the list of wines in the front end app, then you can live with the first option itself. Ember as it is, doesn't give any opinions on how you model your data, and that is left to `ember-data`. Even in Ember data, their philosophy on ember data is described in this [link](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/03/ember-data-progress-update.html)

Comment: I use Ember-Data to build my models and know how to use it, but I was hoping for a persuasive argument for doing it one way or another, which maybe there isn't. However, I'm starting think that it would be easier to get the data via a JOIN query directly in the database rather than pull all of the pieces out of the DB separately.